# SQL: Create a search query multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here a database table with sample entries included:

[image]

What I want to do is create a query that will search a **client_name** using **LIKE**, and that client_name should have a type, and a status, and a credit limit, and a barangay OR a city.

I have tried to mix and match my queries but I cannot seem to get the correct one.

For example, I tried this:

```
select *
from client
where client_name like '%%'
having brgy = '' or city = ''
and type = '' and status = '' 
and credit_limit = ''
order by client_name asc;
```

PS: I also want to do that if I search "anne", all client names with "anne" on it will appear

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using MySQL

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, `HAVING` is for queries that have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Mr.Llama okay so how should I do this now?

Comment: `like '%%'` is pointless. that'll match EVERYTHING. perhaps you just want `client_name is not null`.

Comment: @MarcB what i want to do is that if I search "anne", all client names with "anne" on it will appear

Answer (score 0):

You *do* need parentheses.  You do *not* need a `having` clause.  You do need to understand the difference between equals and not equals:

```
select *
from client
where client_name like '%%' and
      (brgy <> '' or city <> '') and
      type <> '' and status <> '' and
      credit_limit <> ''
order by client_name asc;
```

Note:  if the values are actually `NULL` as opposed to blank, then this version will not work.  You would then need `is not null` rather than `<> ''`.

Comment: How about if I have values that are null? What should I do?

Comment: For nulls, you use "is null", or "is not null". So, it could be ((brgy <> "" and brgy is not null) or (city <> "" and city is not null))

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM client
WHERE `client_name` LIKE '%%'
AND `brgy` NOT NULL AND `city` NOT NULL
AND `type` NOT NULL AND `status` NOT NULL 
AND `credit_limit` NOT NULL
ORDER BY `client_name` ASC;
```